# Dynamic creation of ScheduledExecutorService with variable thread pool at run time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm building a real-time application with multi-threading in Java with executor service.

I'm in the process of writing custom thread pool class that extends `ThreadPoolExecutor` that allows me the flexibility to control my thread pool at run time. Now I need a way schedule tasks to run periodically let's say every minute repeatedly using my custom dynamic thread pool class.

I've explored the `ScheduledExecutorService` but it does not work with my custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` class. Here's the instance creation example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3, new NamedThreadsFactory());
```

I cannot use dynamically created instance of my custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` in this case and can only used fixed number of threads since this is static in nature. Can you suggest some option for a work around? Is there any way to implement my own custom version of `ScheduledExecutorService` so I can:

1. Create a thread pool dynamically, and
2. Schedule tasks using the dynamically created thread pool with `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: The `corePoolSize` arg to `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` is the minimum number of threads to keep at idle. It's not the maximum thread count.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes I'm aware of the corePoolSize parameter and would like to change it at run-time depending on the tasks in the bounded queue

Comment: You can call `setCorePoolSize` at runtime. In any case, it's just a tuning parameter and will make no difference to the number of tasks that you can schedule in parallel.

Comment: It’s just a property of these factory methods in `Executors` not to allow more configuration options than specifying a core pool size. If you instantiate [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly, you get the same options (well, with some restrictions) as with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, simply because it is a subclass of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. And nothing prevents from subclassing `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` just like you extended `ThreadPoolExecutor`…